# Laravel middleware for two users groups

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have in 'users' table two groups of users ( student and teacher ). 
My routing is:

```
Route::get ('/students', 'PanelController@showDegrees')>middleware(['auth', 'student'], function () { return "this page requires that you be logged in and an Student";
```

});

Route::get ('/students/degrees', 'PanelController@showDegrees')>middleware(['auth', 'student'], function () { return "this page requires that you be logged in and an Student";
});

My middleware:

```
class Student
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isStudent ()
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');

}
}
```

My model User (this was in project ) :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'surname', 'status', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function isStudent()
{
    return ($this->status == 'STUDENT') ? true : false;
}
}
```

And Kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'student' => \App\Http\Middleware\Student::class
];
```

The problem is that it actually works but something is wrong... First, my Middleawe Auth::user()->isStudent() doesn't see this function, it write when I hover on this method that is not found in \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Athenticatable... I don't know why.

Second is, that whre can I make redirect, that when user is Student, then rediret to routing /students or /students/degrees?

And third , nowhere is my error from routing function ("this page requires that you be logged in and an Student"), where can I see this?

Comment: in your User Model the function returns with true / false, but the middleware method thinks the returning variable is a string.

Comment: Right I fixed it, but rest od problems are still there

Comment: Second question: `return redirect('/students');` inside the if condition